# Not null violation: 7 ERROR: column "username" of relation "user" contains null values from symfony generated code

Tags: postgresql, symfony, security

I am following the security tutorial from Symfony 6 https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html

I create a User class with email as the unique attribute,

at the moment of migrating the migration via `symfony console doctrine:migration:migrate`,  I get the error

```
exception occurred while executing a query: SQLSTATE[23502]: Not null violation: 7 ERROR:  column "email" of relation "user" contains null values"

In ExceptionConverter.php line 47:

  An exception occurred while executing a query: SQLSTATE[23502]: Not null violation: 7 ERRO  
  R:  column "email" of relation "user" contains null values


In Exception.php line 28:

  SQLSTATE[23502]: Not null violation: 7 ERROR:  column "email" of relation "user" contains   
  null values


In Connection.php line 70:

  SQLSTATE[23502]: Not null violation: 7 ERROR:  column "email" of relation "user" contains   
  null values
```

not sure if a manual change should be done on the generated code in this case, or what is exactly the problem here?

Answer (score 0):

With this little information, im guessing you already have entries in your user table. Truncate the table manually and redo the migrations is what i suggest